# Query with LIKE returning "invalid" items - (where being ignored?)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to recover some complaints registered in the Open311 that contains the string "Noise". That's my URL builder:

```
var start_date = formattedDate(startDate)+"T00:00:00";  //YYYY-MM-DD
var end_date = formattedDate(endDate)+"T23:59:59";      //YYYY-MM-DD
var c_type = 'Noise';                                          // Complaint Type

// Build the data URL
URL = "http://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/erm2-nwe9.json"; // API Access Endpoint
URL += "?";                                                   // A query parameter name is preceded by the question mark
URL += "$where=";                                             // Filters to be applied
URL += "(latitude IS NOT NULL)";                              // Only return records with coordinates
URL += " AND ";
URL += "(complaint_type like '\\%" + c_type + "\\%')";
URL += " AND ";
URL += "(created_date>='" + start_date + "') AND (created_date<='" + end_date + "')"; // Date range
URL += "&$group=complaint_type,descriptor,latitude,longitude";                        // Fields to group by
URL += "&$select=descriptor,latitude,longitude,complaint_type";                       // Fields to return
URL = encodeURI(URL);                               // Encode special characters such as spaces and quotes
URL = URL.replace("'%5C%25", "%27\\%");             // Only way that seems to work in this project
URL = URL.replace("%5C%25'", "\\%%27");
```

And the encoded URL tested:

> [http://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/erm2-nwe9.json?$where=(latitude%20IS%20NOT%20NULL)%20AND%20(complaint_type%20like%20%27\%Noise\%%27)%20AND%20(created_date%3E='2015-12-01T00:00:00')%20AND%20(created_date%3C='2015-12-01T23:59:59')&$group=complaint_type,descriptor,latitude,longitude&$select=descriptor,latitude,longitude,complaint_type](http://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/erm2-nwe9.json?$where=(latitude%20IS%20NOT%20NULL)%20AND%20(complaint_type%20like%20%27%5C%25Noise%5C%25%27)%20AND%20(created_date%3E='2015-12-01T00:00:00')%20AND%20(created_date%3C='2015-12-01T23:59:59')&$group=complaint_type,descriptor,latitude,longitude&$select=descriptor,latitude,longitude,complaint_type)

However, this link contains a LOT of unrelated complaints, in which the filed **complaint_type** doesn't contains the world "Noise".

Why is that? Am I missing something?

Comment: You declared `var c_type = noise` in the top of the scipt. Later on in the query you say `(complaint_type like '\\%" + c_type + "\\%')"`, so your query is correct! (well at least the values are) Correct me if I'm wrong ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an old endpoint which implements version 2.0 of the protocol, with no support for `LIKE`.

You should change the endpoint to `fhrw-4uyv`, which supports 2.1 and LIKE.

Also, your URL construction is quite awful. You should create the values of each of the parameters, and encode each individually using `encodeURIComponent`, then merge them together in the URL. You shouldn't have anything that looks like `\%` in your request.

The bad structure of the URL means it doesn't get parsed correctly and the `$where` is probably completely ignored.

Here's an example of a valid request:

> http://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/fhrw-4uyv.json?$where=(latitude%20IS%20NOT%20NULL)%20AND%20(complaint_type%20LIKE%20%27%25Noise%25%27)%20AND%20(created_date%3E=%272015-11-01T00:00:00%27)%20AND%20(created_date%3C=%272015-12-01T23:59:59%27)&$group=complaint_type,descriptor,latitude,longitude&$select=descriptor,latitude,longitude,complaint_type

Notice the argument to like is `%27%25Noise%25%27` (which is `'%Noise%'`).

Updated code:

```
var c_type = "Noise",
    start_date = "2013-08-01",
    end_date = "2013-08-08";

var condition = "";
condition += "(latitude IS NOT NULL)";                              // Only return records with coordinates
condition += " AND ";
condition += "(complaint_type like '%" + c_type + "%')";
condition += " AND ";
condition += "(created_date>='" + start_date + "') AND (created_date<='" + end_date + "')"; // Date range

var URL;

URL = "http://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/fhrw-4uyv.json"; // API Access Endpoint
URL += "?";                                                   // A query parameter name is preceded by the question mark
URL += "$where=";                                             // Filters to be applied
URL += encodeURIComponent(condition);
URL += "&$group=complaint_type,descriptor,latitude,longitude";                        // Fields to group by
URL += "&$select=descriptor,latitude,longitude,complaint_type";                       // Fields to return
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jacquesc/hczgwdth/2/

Comment: Thank you, @jcaron. I had some trouble to used LIKE, if I don't use \% I always get a bad request. Also, how do I change the endpoint?

Comment: Whatever you were doing with the \ and % results in the URL being malformed, but the contents of the $where being completely ignored. You need to properly format the URL, and not add any \.

Comment: As for the endpoint, there's a line which reads "API Access Endpoint" in your code.

Comment: Using this: URL += "(complaint_type like '%" + c_type + "%')"; I get BAD REQUEST data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/fhrw-4uyv.json?$where=(latitude%20IS%20NOT%20NULL)%20AND%20(complaint_type%20like%20'%25Noise%25')%20AND%20(created_date%3E='2015-12-01T00:00:00')%20AND%20(created_date%3C='2015-12-01T23:59:59')&$group=complaint_type,descriptor,latitude,longitude&$select=descriptor,latitude,longitude,complaint_type

Comment: You have some kind of weird invisible character just before the 4 in `fhrw-4uyv`

Comment: In this example: http://jsfiddle.net/alexk/hczgwdth/1/, if I change `erm2-nwe9` to `fhrw-4uyv`,  the conditions are still ignored.

Comment: Yes, as your URL is still malformed. You need to create the conditions (with no `\`), apply encodeURIComponent() on that, and then compose your URI. http://jsfiddle.net/jacquesc/hczgwdth/2/

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like a fault in your query, more the endpoint doesn't support 'LIKE' (the docs suggest only endpoints from v2.1 do.

Take http://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/erm2-nwe9.json?$where=complaint_type%20like%20%27%27

Even when you strip your query right down it still doesn't work. However,

http://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/erm2-nwe9.json?$where=complaint_type%20=%20%27%25NOISE%25%27

Changing LIKE to an equals sign will work, suggesting the syntax itself is fine.